# How to prevent mouseenter event action with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

I have this simple mouseenter : mouseleave action:

```
call = $('.js-call');

call.on({
    mouseenter: function(e){
       // animation
       e.stopPropagation();
    },
    mouseleave: function(e){
        // animation
    }
});
```

In this action i have two CSS animations, which have a duration of 300ms. How can I prevent mouseover event for animation end, and fire it again if i'm properly on call element. When i moving fast on my call element action call many times. How to prevent it? Thx for help.

Comment: Use jQuery to animate instead of CSS transitions, you'll have more control over the result. Also, can you show us more? css... inner fn... something?

Comment: bc i have rotations and transforms in this animation and i can't do this with jquery animation ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with placing timeouts on both events, and activate the animation only if at the end of that timeout you still meet a condition. Something like that:

```
var timeoutIn, timeoutOut, delay = 300;
$element.hover(
    function() {
        if (timeoutOut){
            clearTimeout(timeoutOut);
        }
        timeoutIn = setTimeout(function() {
            // ##################
            // 'MOUSEENTER' STUFF GOES HERE
            // ##################
        }, delay);
    },
    function() {
        if (timeoutIn){
            clearTimeout(timeoutIn);
        }
        timeoutOut = setTimeout(function() {
            // ##################
            // 'MOUSELEAVE' STUFF GOES HERE
            // ##################
        }, delay);
    }
);
```

**Update**: I've just created a jQuery plugin called jQuery.hoverDelay.js, you can check it out here: <kbd>[**jQuery hoverDelay.js**](http://ronency.github.io/hoverDelay/)</kbd>

Comment: much thx, this works perfect, thx for solving the real problem :)

Answer (score 0):

what you could do is use `.bind( eventType [, eventData ], handler(eventObject) )`.

bind the event mouseleave after you're done with the animation and vice versa. this should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery [.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) is the correct approach.

Heres a working fiddle starting and stoping an animation with mouseenter and mousleave, without starting new animation if theres already running one.

http://jsfiddle.net/CZtLe/

```
function animateMe(element, color) {
    element.stop(true).animate({
        backgroundColor: color,
        duration: 300
    });
}

$(function () {
    call = $('.js-call');
    call.on({
        mouseenter: function (e) {
            animateMe($(this), '#FF0000');
            e.stopPropagation();
        },
        mouseout: function (e) {
            animateMe($(this), '#000000');
        }
    });

});
```